# Not able to add Group Feature

Tags: elgg

Was trying out Elgg-1.8.19, all was going smooth but got stuck up in Group Part. Want to have Group feature where user can create groups. Below images might give light on issue. To be more specific how to add "Group plugin" refer below image(red highlighted)

[image]

Any help would really appreciated. Thanks

Update: some one suggested "You have to enable the groups plugin first before being able to enable the Group UX plugin. The groups plugin comes bundled with Elgg. Additionally, the group_tools plugin is suggested (not required). The group_tools plugin can be downloaded at http://community.elgg.org/plugins/736791/2.10/group-tools."

But the issue still remains , check image
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got my problem solved . Elgg is offered in 2 licence one is MIT and Other is GNU. If you download from Home page(elgg.org) you get MIT version which doesn't contains external plugins due to licencing issue and i had this copy, so Groups issue.So downloaded from http://elgg.org/download.php which was GNU version and had group plugin. added the "Group" plugin from GNU version to present working MIT version. Thanks and Enjoy. More info about issue can be found at http://community.elgg.org/discussion/view/1826435/not-able-to-add-group-feature .

Answer (score 1):

Groups is one of the bundled plugins available with all Elgg GPLv2 distributions (MIT version is stripped of the plugins due to licensing issues). If you're not using MIT version, you should have Groups plugin on the list. Just need to enable it first.

If you're using MIT distribution, check [Licensing FAQ](http://learn.elgg.org/en/latest/intro/license.html) and consider if using one GPLv2 plugin is fine for you.

Comment: Thanks. This is the version i am using http://elgg.org/download.php ---> Elgg 1.8.19. Still searing in which licencing does it belong to.

Comment: MIT versions are in separate frame with download links and have `-mit` suffix in the downloaded file as well as empty mod folder. When in doubt, check LICENSE file on root dir of your Elgg install. If you used main download button, you should have GPLv2 version.